# Bootstrap: Add button or clickable glyph inline with list group item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve the following in Bootstrap, but am having some difficulty.

I have a clickable list group of the form

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">first item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">third item</a>
</div>
```

I would like to display a button (or clickable glyph) to the left of each item (inline and with some margin). How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
<div class="list-group test">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> first item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> second item</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> third item</a>
</div>

.test a span {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```